# Counting how many unique values each pixel contains across rasters/layers

Tags: qgis, raster, land-cover

I am using QGIS.

I have 20 large rasters showing land cover over 20 years ([MCD12Q1](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mcd12q1v006/)). Each pixel contains a value between 1 and 17 that corresponds to a land cover class.

I am trying to create a new raster that shows how many unique land cover classes each pixel has experienced across the 20 yearly rasters. For example, if a pixel was forested, then became grassland for a few years, and then reverted back to forest, that pixel in the new raster would have a value of 2.

I am relatively new to all of this, but I've tried exploring online and asking others and haven't found a solution yet. I have tried using a loop to index each pixel across the rasters, then use the R *unique* and *length* commands to "count" unique values like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(layer2001)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(layer2001)){
    
    sub = as.numeric(unique(s[[1:20]][i,j]))
    sub = unique(sub)
    temp = as.numeric(length(sub))
    
    newrast[cellFromRowCol(newrast,i,j)][1] <- temp
    
  }
}
```

but because of the size of the rasters this is not a solution. I have also been pointed towards the *stackApply* command but haven't been able to use it successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Cell statistics`. For `Statistics`, select `Variety` (count of unique values). See details in the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#cell-statistics).